# Parsing text files to a matrix using python

Tags: python, function, parsing, python-3.x, matrix

A chocolate company has decided to offer discount on the candy products which are produced 30 days of more before the current date. I have to have a matrix as a print result where the program reads through 2 files, one being the the cost of the different candies of different sizes, and another being the threshold number of days after which the discount is offered. 
So basically, everywhere the number is under 30(which is the input from days.txt) it should print a `"$"` sign and everywhere it is more than the number(30 in our case) it should just print spaces in their place. We also have an anomally, where we have the english alphabets in the candies.txt matrix and since we are looking for numbers to check the price and not letters, it should print a `"?"` sign in their place as it is not recognized.

Here is what I am trying to do.

```
candy = []
with open('demo.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
    if len(line) > 0:
        candy.append(map(int, line.split()))
print(candy, end='')

parsedList=[]
with open("demo.txt","r") as f:
    lst=f.read().splitlines()
    for i in lst:
        parsedList.append(i.split())
with open("days.txt","r") as f:
    param = int(f.readline().split("=")[1])

for innerList in parsedList:
    for element in innerList:
        if element.isdigit():
            if int(element)>=param:
                print (" ", end='')
            else:
                print( "$", end='')
        else:
            print ("?", end='')
    print(string, end='')
```

My question is that I am trying to have the file demo.txt printed and then have python print the output with replaced values in a matrix form. My values are printing but they are not in the matrix and its also not printing the 1st text file.

Comment: your very first if statement is not indented properly. and what do you mean my "My values are printing but they are not in the matrix"? if you mean that everything is printing as a new line, use `print(string, end='')` to avoid the new line

Comment: I edited it some. Not sure that's how you meant to stop the new line

Comment: Your input file seems to have a different format, you are splitting using commas (,)

Comment: Sorry about that. I was doing another file which had commas and forgot to remove them. I have edited it now.

Comment: no i meant replacing all your current print functions and adding the `end=''` token. dont replace the one that you did, that one is necessary because you do want a newline for every file. regardless, @LetzerWille posted a very good answer

Comment: Oh ok. I saw that answer but he does not parse the data from out input files.

Comment: I edited some but its still not creating a matrix or printing the original demo.txt in the output

Answer (score 1):

```
def repl(ch,threshold):
    if ch.isdigit():
        if int(ch) < threshold:
            return '$'
        elif int(ch)> threshold:
            return " "
        else:
            return ch
    else:
        return '?'
lines = []
with open('data') as f, open("data.txt","r") as f2:
    threshold = int(f2.read().split('=')[-1])
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        line = line.split()
        line = [repl(ch,threshold) for ch in line]
        lines.append(line)
    # reset to start of demo.txt
    f.seek(0)
    for line in f:
        print(line)

for line in lines:
    print()
    for el in line:
        print(el,end=" ")

31 32 19 11 15 30 35 37

12 34 39 45 66 78 12 7

76 32 8 2 3 5 18 32 48

99 102 3 46 88 22 25 21

fd zz er 23 44 56 77 99

44 33 22 55 er ee df 22

    $ $ $ 30     
$           $ $ 
    $ $ $ $ $     
    $     $ $ $ 
? ? ? $         
    $   ? ? ? $
```

Comment: We need to use the 2 text files and parse data from them. It cannot be hard coded.

Comment: @StarryNight ok. in the days.txt will be at days a list of dates, or it will be a tuple I mean: Discount at days = [30,29,21...] or (30,28,32) ?

Comment: In days.txt, it is exactly as I have shown above. It will be like `Discount at days = 30` . Now the values can change from 30 and it can be anything but we will have to use both demo.txt and days.txt for our data.

Comment: @StarryNight ok. Take a look. now will use the days.txt

Comment: But we also have to use demo.txt where the matrix values are present.

Comment: @StarryNight data is your demo.txt. I just named so on my comp. I will update the name

Comment: Yes it is. What is the purpose of 

`[[' ', ' ', '$', '$', '$', '30', ' ', ' '],
 ['$', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '$', '$'],
 [' ', ' ', '$', '$', '$', '$', '$', ' ', ' '],
 [' ', ' ', '$', ' ', ' ', '$', '$', '$'],
 ['?', '?', '?', '$', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
 [' ', ' ', '$', ' ', '?', '?', '?', '$']]`

Comment: @StarryNight it is how prettyprint shows the structure of lines. lines is a list of lists, two dimensional structure

Comment: @StarryNight I will add printout as you need it.

Comment: @StarryNight values are not hardcoded in the code. Printing from demo.txt  is not hard. One has to reset to start of file. I'll update now

Comment: Ok that worked. One more thing. How do we print the entire contents of both the text files as output? I mean it should print the demo.txt first, then days.txt and then our final output as calculated?

Comment: @StarryNight it does now, take a look

Comment: Thank you Very much!!! It works! Can you also explain what does el mean in `for el in line:
        print(el,end=" ")`

Comment: @StarryNight end= "  " specifies that space will be use instead of newline

Comment: @StarryNight el is element of line, which is a list.

Comment: I have a question, on line 15 `line = [repl(ch,threshold) for ch in line]` can we write this statement in another way? Like without using square brackets?

Comment: Also on line 12 `with open('data') as f, open("data.txt","r") as f2:
`